# Better way (more elegant) to add character to string

Tags: java, formatting, substring

I have a `String` like `8890` and I want to transform to `88,90`.
There are a more elegant way that this?

```
    String s = "8890";
    s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 2) + "," + s.substring(s.length() - 2);
    System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: you're right! I changed my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this is more elegant to you

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("8890");
sb.insert(2, ',');
System.out.println(sb);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to format a decimal number, why not do that?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String s = "8890";
    final BigDecimal dec = new BigDecimal(s).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100));
    final String formatted = new DecimalFormat("0.00", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH)).format(dec);
    System.out.println(formatted);
}
```

Just pick a `Locale` where the decimal separator is the one you want - I chose `French`.

Output:

```
88,90
```

Alternatively set the `setMinimumFractionDigits` on the default instance:

```
final NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH);
format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
final String formatted = format.format(dec);
```

The result is the same.

**EDIT**

OP's comment *It's €uro format*. In that case there is an existing formatter that does exactly that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String s = "8890";
    final BigDecimal dec = new BigDecimal(s).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100));
    final String formatted = DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE).format(dec);
    System.out.println(formatted);
}
```

Will output:

```
88,90 €
```

Picking a country where they use a leading €, such as Italy, will result in:

```
€ 88,90
```

Comment: +1 for using correct tools which say exactly what code is suppose to do.

Answer (score 0):

`s = String.format("%s,%s", s.substring(0, 2), s.substring(2));`